# Siri to speak push notification in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, siri, sirikit

Can we use Siri to read push notifications in iOS 10 using Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I'd recommend diving more into the documentation to find out how it works. SiriKit supports a limited set of functions that it categorises into "domains". The idea is that Siri is prepared to do all the work (for multiple languages) but they have to design how we interface with it, so there's only a few things it does at the moment.

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SiriDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH9-SW2).